# Uploading a file using Angular js - protractor e2e testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, protractor, e2e-testing

i want to upload a file as an automated test, with the following code, it correctly selects the file & clicks the upload button, however nothing happens after the upload button is clicked, I believe its not triggering the javascript on the page:

```
var fileUpload = './testFile.txt',
absolutePath = path.resolve('./testFile.txt', fileUpload);
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);

element(by.model('documentFile'));

element(by.css('button[ng-click="uploadSelectedFiles()"]')).click();
```

Is there another method for this?

EDIT: I have managed to do this, thank you to who helped me, here is my code:

```
var fileUpload = './testFile.jpg',
            absolutePath = path.resolve('/home/xxx/workspace/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx/test/x/x/x/x/filesToUpload', fileUpload);

        var uploadInput = $('input[type="file"]');
        uploadInput.sendKeys(absolutePath);
        uploadInput.submit();
        element(by.css('button[ng-click="uploadSelectedFiles()"]')).click();
```

Comment: could you provide html code?

Comment: HTML for chooseFile:
    <input ng-file-select="selectFiles($files)" class="peg-e2e-batch-    upload ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="documentFile" name="file" ng-accept="'.jpg, .pdf'" ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" required="" type="file">





html for uploadButton:
    <button class="btn btn-private-primary pull-left" ng-    click="uploadSelectedFiles()">Submit</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clicking "upload" button, send keys to the input to set the path and submit the form by clicking `Submit` button:

```
var uploadInput = $('input[type="file"]');

uploadInput.sendKeys(absolutePath);

var submitButton = element(by.xpath("//input[.='Submit']"));
submitButton.click();
```

Comment: it is still not uploading the file, selecting it correctly but not submitting form, i even tried putting in a browser.pause(); & submitting the file manually, still nothing happens.

Comment: so you are not able to perform such kind of action manually also? in this case it is problem in application itself

Comment: @Jordan.Muscat can you also edit the question and include the complete HTML code for the form and `uploadSelectedFiles()` function implementation.

Comment: How is that a correct answer? `ng-click` on the button won't be triggered if you just submit the form.

Comment: @meze question is, do u need to click the upload button to get stuck with the choose file dialog that u cannot control with selenium? The idea here is to set the path to the file via sendKeys and submit the form.

Comment: I assumed there's a FileReader or something in `uploadSelectedFiles()` that handles uploading and when a user uploads a file it's never submitted as a plain form. Unless  `ng-submit` is specified, `.submit()` will send a file to the server but  `uploadSelectedFiles()` won't be called, therefore it's not covered by the test.

Comment: @Jordan.Muscat please check the update - should submit the form now.

Comment: @meze correct, I've improved the answer. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a space between "ng-" and "click".